# Pandas checking equality with NA values yields NA

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 1], [2, 3]], dtype='float64')
```

When I check the equality of the values with `df == 1`, I get the following DataFrame:

```py
      0      1
0 False   True
1 False  False
```

Which I consider a normal behaviour. However, if I choose `'Int64'` (capital `I`, because `'int64'` does not have `NaN`s) instead of `'float64'`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 1], [2, 3]], dtype='Int64')
```

Which, printed out, is:

```py
      0  1
0  <NA>  1
1     2  3
```

and I try the same comparison as before (`df == 1`), I get:

```py
      0      1
0  <NA>  False
1 False  False
```

First of all, I don't see why `1 == 1` would yield `False` (0, 1). Then, I don't see either why the comparison with `<NA>` does not yield `False` as it does with `float`s.

Is there another way of comparing than `==` which would make this work?

EDIT:
My pandas version is 1.0.4

Comment: Not reproducible. I get `True` for cell `1` in second case as well. My pandas version is `1.0.3`.

Comment: what version is your pandas? I get `True` for (0,1) with version 1.0.3.

Comment: Can you give us the output of `print(pd.__version__)`

Comment: Updated in pandas 1.0.4: 2+2=5

Comment: I get `True` for (0,1) for both version 1.0.3 and 1.0.4

Comment: @Stef when I check if the value is equal to 1, it works, but not as a vectorized operation. `df.loc[0, 1] == 1` yields `True` but not when I use `df == 1`

Comment: very strange: I get `True` for `df.loc[0, 1] == 1` and `df == 1` for both versions 1.0.3 and 1.0.4

Answer (score 2):

> I don't see either why the comparison with `<NA>` does not yield `False` as it does with `floats`. Is there another way of comparing than `==` which would make this work?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 1], [2, 3]], dtype='Int64')
df.notna() & df.eq(1)
#       0      1
#0  False   True
#1  False  False
```

`<NA>` propagates in any binary operation ([source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1ce1c3c1ef9894bf1ba79805f37514291f52a9da/pandas/_libs/missing.pyx#L296)). Please also note [the following warning](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1ce1c3c1ef9894bf1ba79805f37514291f52a9da/pandas/_libs/missing.pyx#L341):

> Experimental: the behaviour of NA can still change without warning.

See also the example "comparison" [in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html#operations) which corresponds to your example.

Answer (score 1):

To be as concise as possible, I ended up using:

```py
(df == 1) is True
```

Which is `False` if `df == 1` yields `<NA>`